# how do i add new fields in a firebase collection document when using classes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to add a new field to a document but I am not able.

here is the class that I am using::

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:thraive/constants/diary.dart';

import '../../constants/all_tables.dart';
import '../../constants/place.dart';

@immutable
class CloudPlace {
  final String documentId;
  final bool active;
  final String created_by;
  final Timestamp created_on;
  final String image_url;
  final String place_description;
  final bool? is_place_rated;



  const CloudPlace({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.active,
    required this.created_by,
    required this.created_on,
    required this.image_url,
    required this.place_description,
    required this.is_place_rated,
  });

  // acts as constructor
  CloudPlace.singleDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        active = snapshot.data()![activeColumn],
        created_by = snapshot.data()![createdByColumn] as String,
        created_on = snapshot.data()![createdOnColumn] as Timestamp,
        image_url = snapshot.data()![place_imageUrlColumn] as String,
        place_description = snapshot.data()![place_placeDescriptionColumn] as String,
        is_place_rated = snapshot.data()![place_isPlaceRated] as bool;

  // acts as constructor
  CloudPlace.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        active = snapshot.data()[activeColumn],
        created_by = snapshot.data()[createdByColumn] as String,
        created_on = snapshot.data()[createdOnColumn] as Timestamp,
        image_url = snapshot.data()[place_imageUrlColumn] as String,
        place_description = snapshot.data()[place_placeDescriptionColumn] as String,
        is_place_rated = snapshot.data()[place_isPlaceRated] as bool;

        
}
```

the issue is with is_place_rated.
the issue is that other documents don't have that field so I am getting this error::

```
I/flutter (12868): type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' in type cast
```

I tried to set a default value of false but that didn't not work::

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:thraive/constants/diary.dart';

import '../../constants/all_tables.dart';
import '../../constants/place.dart';

@immutable
class CloudPlace {
  final String documentId;
  final bool active;
  final String created_by;
  final Timestamp created_on;
  final String image_url;
  final String place_description;
  final bool? is_place_rated;



  const CloudPlace({
    required this.documentId,
    required this.active,
    required this.created_by,
    required this.created_on,
    required this.image_url,
    required this.place_description,
    this.is_place_rated,
  });

  // acts as constructor
  CloudPlace.singleDoc(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        active = snapshot.data()![activeColumn],
        created_by = snapshot.data()![createdByColumn] as String,
        created_on = snapshot.data()![createdOnColumn] as Timestamp,
        image_url = snapshot.data()![place_imageUrlColumn] as String,
        place_description = snapshot.data()![place_placeDescriptionColumn] as String,
        is_place_rated = snapshot.data()![place_isPlaceRated] as bool?? false;

  // acts as constructor
  CloudPlace.fromSnapshot(QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot)
      : documentId = snapshot.id,
        active = snapshot.data()[activeColumn],
        created_by = snapshot.data()[createdByColumn] as String,
        created_on = snapshot.data()[createdOnColumn] as Timestamp,
        image_url = snapshot.data()[place_imageUrlColumn] as String,
        place_description = snapshot.data()[place_placeDescriptionColumn] as String,
        is_place_rated = snapshot.data()[place_isPlaceRated] as bool ?? false;

        
}
```

how can I fix this issue?

Comment: why are you casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to check whether the field exists or not first.

```
is_place_rated = snapshot.data().toString().contains(place_isPlaceRated)? snapshot.get(place_isPlaceRated): false;
```